# VPN/IPsec router support in Packet Tracer

Tags: cisco, vpn, ipsec, packet-tracer

I would like to know, if a router doesn't support VPN (meaning it can't be used as a VPN server) can it still route an IPsec packet?
And which router I should use as a server for IPSec (AH tunnel mode) site-to-site VPN ?

I was using Router-PT in my packet tracer file, but when I wanted to configure IPSec VPN I need to change it and I'm wondering if I have to change all routers that my packet passes by.

Thank you.

Comment: Packet Tracer is limited to getting you through the CCNA exam, and it is missing many advanced features of real devices.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I'm aware of that, but in my networking class, they asked us to work with it, so we don't really have much choice.

Comment: Almost nobody here uses that, so we really cannot help much. Threre are hundreds of sites for network education help.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

IPsec packets are just IP packets with encrypted payloads.  Routers are unaware of the payload, so it doesn't matter if it's encrypted or not.